# How to simplify the resistor with base current in BJT?

Tags: bjt

Attached below is the circuit of BJT for the sake of practice.

In this BJT circuit, any ideas to simplify the circuit in the blue rectangle (base part) in order to calculate base current, IB?

[image]

(Updated work above. See prior picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSaU7.png).)

Comment: Just treat R1 and R2 and your voltage source with a Thevenin equivalent of just one voltage source and one resistor in series with it. It's just a voltage divider. Does that make sense? (It should as before you start on BJT schematics, you should have been exposed much earlier to Thevenin and Norton.)

Comment: Can you apply a Thevenin equivalent for us and attempt to find the base current, with a discussion in your edited question?

Comment: @jonk https://imgur.com/a/XBRC7AG I believe I have obtained the answer after receiving ur tips!

Comment: Yup. Looks like you did it fine in the upper right corner there. You can, if you wish, write up your own answer to your question and then select it. No one else has added anything, anyway. And it helps others to have your approach as an answer.

Comment: When you feel you've waited long enough to see if there may be answers you like better, you can select an answer. The reason to do this isn't because you want to please someone else who wrote an answer. In fact, I hope that is never your reason. But doing so does help others avoid wasting their own time, thinking you didn't get what you needed already and where they take a lot of their time because they just want to help you out in a different way.  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for adding the new image with your added work. The original schematic is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPcKtH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've redrawn it (on left) for clarity. There's no need to show the voltage sources or the fact that they are ground-referenced.

You are right in your notes that the zener diode (\$D_1\$ above) isn't active as its zener voltage is higher than the supply rail voltage. So there will be no current in \$R_{_\text{D}}\$ and therefore also no drop across it. As a consequence the schematic does immediately simplify to the schematic on right. As you realized.

You took a moment to show your Thevenin equivalent for the base resistor divider pair, too, in the upper right corner of your new image. Leading to this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkcWyG.png)</sup>

That's also correctly done, with the Thevenin resistance being \$\frac1{11}\cdot 39\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

Your KVL (upper middle of image) is:

$$\begin{align*}2\:\text{V} &=  R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot I_{_\text{B}} + V_{_\text{BE}} + R_{_\text{E}}\cdot  I_{_\text{E}}\\\\2\:\text{V} &=  R_{_\text{TH}}\cdot I_{_\text{B}} + V_{_\text{BE}} + R_{_\text{E}}\cdot  I_{_\text{B}}\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)\end{align*}$$

And this is also correct.

Knowing that \$\beta=140\$ the above does solve out as \$I_{_\text{B}}\approx 6.045\:\mu\text{A}\$, just as you wrote out.

I compute:

$$V_{_\text{CE}}=22\:\text{V}-\left[\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_{_\text{B}}\right]\cdot R_{_\text{E}} - \left[\beta\cdot I_{_\text{B}}\right]\cdot R_{_\text{C}}\approx 12.26\:\text{V}$$

And that is remarkably close (I used exact values) to what you wrote on the middle left of your image.

Finally, this indicates that the BJT is in active mode so that the analysis assumptions made (the value of \$\beta\$) are valid and therefore the results hold.

So I think you did just fine.

Best wishes!